# Conditional expectation of uniform distribution

Tags: conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

I'm studying economics and there are two different solutions from different problems. I wonder what is the difference.

(1) Let $\theta$ is uniform distribution. Then
$E(θ|θ ≤ P) =\frac{\int^{P}_{-\infty}θf(θ)dθ}{F(P)}$
(2) Let $\theta$ is uniform distribution [0,1]. Then
$E(θ|θ ≤ P) =\frac{P}{2}$

If we apply (1) formula to (2), the outcome is $\frac{1}{2P}$.
Is there any missing point that I lost?

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{2P}$? (1) should also lead to $\frac{P}{2}$ for $P\in (0,1)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 $E(θ|θ ≤ P) =\frac{\int^{P}_{0}θf(θ)dθ}{F(P)}=\frac{\int^{P}_{0}θf(θ)dθ}{\int^{P}_{0}dθ}=\frac{\int^{P}_{0} θ (1/2) dθ}{\int^{P}_{0}dθ}=\frac{1}{2}$ in here which part is wrong?

Comment: It should be $\frac{\int_0^P\theta\;d\theta}{P}=\frac{P^2}{2P}=\frac{P}{2}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Oh.. right! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
E[\theta| \theta \le P] &= \int_0^P \theta f_{\theta|\theta \le P}(\theta|\theta \le P)d\theta \\
&= \int_0^P \theta \frac{Pr([\theta-\epsilon,\theta+\epsilon]\cap \{\theta \le P\})}{Pr(\{\theta \le P\})} d\theta \\ 
&= \int_0^P \theta \frac{f(\theta)}{F(P)} d\theta\\
&= \int_0^P \theta \frac{1}{F(P)} d\theta  && \text{$U\sim[0,1]$ so $f(\theta)=1$} \\ 
&=\frac{1}{P}\int_0^P\theta d\theta \\
&=\frac{P^2}{2P}= \frac{P}{2}
\end{align*}

So the first definition is correct.